# Join on condition if columns values are equal only, else different join condition

Tags: sql, join

I would like to join two table if the values are equal , if not do the second join on different column

1. for records where a.column_1=b.column_2(are equal) use join on  a.column_1=b.column_2
2. for records where a.column_1 <> b.column_2 use the new join a.column_3 = b.column_2

Is this approach possible? If so, please help.

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected results.

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  You should provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
SELECT *
FROM 
  TABLE_A AS A
, TABLE_B AS B
WHERE
    ( a.column_1 =  b.column_2 )
OR  ( a.column_1 <> b.column_2 AND a.column_3 = b.column_2 )
```

Answer (score 0):

One method uses two `left join`s.

```
select ...
from a
left join b b2 on b2.col2 = a.col2
left join b b3 on b3.col3 = a.col3
where b2.col2 is not null or b3.col3 is not null
```

This avoids "multiplying" the rows when both conditions match. Then you can address the columns with `coalesce()`, giving the priority to `b2`.

```
select a.*, coalesce(b2.col4, b3.col4) b_col4, coalesce(b2.col5, b3.col5) b_col5
from a
left join b b2 on b2.col2 = a.col2
left join b b3 on b3.col3 = a.col3
where b2.col2 is not null or b3.col3 is not null
```

Answer (score 0):

This is often done with two `join`s (and `coalesce()`):

```
select a.*,
       coalesce(b1.col3, b2.col3) as col3
from a left join
     b b1
     on a.column_1 = b1.column_2 left join
     b b2
     on a.column_3 = b2.column_2 and b1.column_2 is null
where b1.column_2 is not null or b2.column_2 is not null;
```